# Empezar contador con c# y VB.NET a partir de 001?

Tags: c#, vb.net, contador

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 enlace.Codigo = DateTime.Now.Year +"/"+ alta_comunicados.Count.ToString("001");
```

Pero no funciona bien, no empieza desde el 001 a contar. Que está fallando?

**alta_comunicados** es una lista de objetos. Lo que hace es acceder a la clase correspondiente para luego poder hacer el insert.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que tipo es `alta_comunicados`? ¿Que es lo que quieres conseguir? Te falta esa información a la pregunta para poder saber que es lo que buscas, de lo contrario **no está claro lo que se pregunta**.

Comment: alta_comunicados por decirlo de alguna forma son los comunicados que voy subiendo. Lo que hace la funcionalidad de arriba es ir contando todos los comunicados. Si pongo "000" empieza a contar desde "000", luego "001" etc y funciona bien, pero quisiera que empezara a contar desde "000". Por cierto. No sé quien ha puesto el -1, pero estaría bien que en vez de poner -1 dijerais que más os puede faltar para intentar ayudarme, como ha hecho @Marc .

Comment: Sigo sin entender que es lo que buscas, **Edita la pregunta** añadiendo esa información, no has dicho que tipo es `alta_comunicados` aun. Añade la información a la pregunta y aclara que es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo tu pregunta mucho. Pero para empezar, `.ToString("001");` es incorrecto, si lo que quieres formatear `Count` a 3 digitos, lo correcto es `.ToString("000");`. Pero eso simplemente es el formato, no tiene nada que ver con _"a partir de que numero empieza a contar"_. Empezará a contar con el valor de `Count`

Comment: Con `ToString("000")` le estás diciendo el formato del número, pero no que cambies el resultado de la cuenta, me explico, si le pones "101" no es que el resultado sea 101+`Count`, sino que te dará 1`Count`1, es decir, si el valor de `Count` es 14 te dará 1141, los ceros indican la posición del resultado del `Count`.

Y Count no empieza a contar por 0, te indica que hay 0 elementos, por lo que hay algo que no cuadra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras releer la pregunta, creo que entiendo cual es el problema.

Analicemos tu código:

```
enlace.Codigo = DateTime.Now.Year +"/"+ alta_comunicados.Count.ToString("001");
```

La primera vez que lo ejecutes, `alta_comunicados` no tiene elementos, por lo que `alta_comunicados.Count` devuelve 0. Estás intentando forzar incorrectamente a que la cuenta de elementos empiece por `1` usando el formateo de cadena, lo que no va a funcionar nunca porque lo único que hace es adaptar el valor de `Count` a la cadena de formateo, en ningún caso va a sumarle 1.

La solución es mucho mas sencilla: sumar siempre `1` a `alta_comunicados.Count`:

```
enlace.Codigo = DateTime.Now.Year +"/"+ (alta_comunicados.Count+1).ToString("000");
```

El formateo del numero entiendo que quieres que siempre contenga 3 digitos, por lo que lo correcto es usar como cadena de formateo `"000"`.